# Dealing with time series in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Im struggling with handling time series in SQL. Straight to the point, lets assume that i have following table with data as below:

| Value A | Value B | TimeStamp | AmountA | AmountB | RunID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | A | 25/04/21 | 100 | 100 | 1 |
| T1 | B | 25/04/21 | 100 | 100 | 1 |
| T1 | A | 26/04/21 | 120 | 100 | 2 |
| T1 | B | 26/04/21 | 150 | 100 | 2 |
| T1 | A | 27/04/21 | 110 | 110 | 3 |
| T1 | B | 27/04/21 | 140 | 130 | 3 |
| T1 | A | 27/04/21 | 125 | 90 | 4 |
| T1 | B | 27/04/21 | 120 | 190 | 4 |

I want to achieve following result :

| TimeStamp | A_AMOUNT_A | B_AMOUNT_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25/04/21 | 100 | 100 |
| 26/04/21 | 120 | 150 |
| 27/04/21 | 125 | 120 |

Usually to deal with time series i'm using following syntax:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP,MAX( CASE WHEN VALUE B='A' THEN AMOUNTA),MAX( CASE WHEN VALUE B='B' THEN AMOUNTA)
FROM SOMETABLE GROUP BY TIMESTAMP
```

The output of above query returns:

| TIMESTAMP | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25/04/21 | 100 | 100 |
| 26/04/21 | 120 | 150 |
| 27/04/21 | 125 | 140 |

I understand that query returns the MAX value for specified conditions hence the output is incorrect, the question is how can modify the query to consider runID and choose the value for max RunID or what is more usefull for me, something like: where for a given day and given value B there are two entries return the AmountA with highest run id.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's better to provide test data in the following form:

```sql
with t(a,b,tmstmp,AmountA,AmountB,RunID) as (
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('25/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 100, 100, 1 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('25/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 100, 100, 1 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('26/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 120, 100, 2 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('26/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 150, 100, 2 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 110, 110, 3 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 140, 130, 3 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 125,  90, 4 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 120, 190, 4 from dual
)
select * from t;
```

Re your main question:

you can use `max()keep()` (also known as `FIRST`) aggregate function ([FIRST and LAST functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/FIRST.html)):

```sql
SELECT 
     tmstmp
    ,MAX( CASE WHEN B='A' THEN AMOUNTA END)
        keep(dense_rank first order by RunID desc) A
    ,MAX( CASE WHEN B='B' THEN AMOUNTA END)
        keep(dense_rank first order by RunID desc) B
FROM t 
GROUP BY tmstmp;
```

Full example with test data:

```sql
with t(a,b,tmstmp,AmountA,AmountB,RunID) as (
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('25/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 100, 100, 1 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('25/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 100, 100, 1 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('26/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 120, 100, 2 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('26/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 150, 100, 2 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 110, 110, 3 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 140, 130, 3 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 125,  90, 4 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 120, 190, 4 from dual
)
SELECT 
     tmstmp
    ,MAX( CASE WHEN B='A' THEN AMOUNTA END)
        keep(dense_rank first order by RunID desc) A
    ,MAX( CASE WHEN B='B' THEN AMOUNTA END)
        keep(dense_rank first order by RunID desc) B
FROM t 
GROUP BY tmstmp;

-- results:
TMSTMP                       A          B
------------------- ---------- ----------
2021-04-25 00:00:00        100        100
2021-04-26 00:00:00        120        150
2021-04-27 00:00:00        125        120
```

Also you can make it easier using `PIVOT` clause:

```sql
SELECT 
     A
    ,TMSTMP
    ,AGG_A_AA
    ,AGG_B_AA
    ,AGG_A_AB
    ,AGG_B_AB
FROM t 
pivot (
       max(AmountA) keep(dense_rank first order by RunID) as AA
     , max(AmountB) keep(dense_rank first order by RunID) as AB
     for B in ('A'as agg_a, 'B' as agg_b)
);
```

Full example with test data:

```sql
with t(a,b,tmstmp,AmountA,AmountB,RunID) as (
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('25/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 100, 100, 1 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('25/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 100, 100, 1 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('26/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 120, 100, 2 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('26/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 150, 100, 2 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 110, 110, 3 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 140, 130, 3 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'A', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 125,  90, 4 from dual union all
    select 'T1', 'B', to_timestamp('27/04/21','dd/mm/yy'), 120, 190, 4 from dual
)
SELECT 
     A
    ,TMSTMP
    ,AGG_A_AA
    ,AGG_B_AA
    ,AGG_A_AB
    ,AGG_B_AB
FROM t 
pivot (
       max(AmountA) keep(dense_rank first order by RunID) as AA
     , max(AmountB) keep(dense_rank first order by RunID) as AB
     for B in ('A'as agg_a, 'B' as agg_b)
);
-------------------------
-- Results:
A  TMSTMP                AGG_A_AA   AGG_B_AA   AGG_A_AB   AGG_B_AB
-- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
T1 2021-04-25 00:00:00        100        100        100        100
T1 2021-04-26 00:00:00        120        150        100        100
T1 2021-04-27 00:00:00        110        140        110        130
```

As you can see, it aggregates not only `AmountA`, but `AmountB` too, and automat(g)ically.

PS. Don't use `timestamp` for column names, it's a special word for [timestamp literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1__GUID-D8999522-88C6-41D7-96BA-D782CA3543DD)

Comment: +1 for the `pivot`. I argue that is the best answer, because it makes it clear what you're doing at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use aggregation with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT TR.*
FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMP, RUNID,
             MAX(CASE WHEN VALUEB = 'A' THEN AMOUNTA END) AS A,
             MAX(CASE WHEN VALUEB = 'B' THEN AMOUNTA END) AS B,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TIMESTAMP ORDER BY RUNID DESC) AS SEQNUM
      FROM SOMETABLE
      GROUP BY TIMESTAMP, RUNID
     ) TR
WHERE SEQNUM = 1
```